# Cut lines from text file

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm lookig for solution to cut data from text files. The example files looks like:

```
text1
------------
line1
line2
linen

text2
----------
```

I would like to grab only line1 line2 and linen so I would like to extract data between signs '-' and text2

Where I should start? What is easiest way in Powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Regex` or `Select-String`:

```
$textContent = 'text1
------------
line1
line2
linen

text2
----------'
($textContent | Select-String -Pattern '(?<=-{12})([\s\S]*?)(?=text2)').Matches.Value
```

Comment: Thank You very much! That is exactly what I'm looking for.